# Really messed up SVN in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn

I really know very little about SVN and I'm trying to learn what it's all about but I have seriously screwed up my project. The project itself is fine (still builds, runs, etc) but I can't do anything with the SVN.

I'm using VisualSVN server as the repository(?) on my server, and TortoiseSVN on my dev pc, with AnkhSVN as the VS plugin.

So the problems I'm having are

- Trying to commit my solution I get "Solution is locked" in ankhSVN and "solution is locked, please use the cleanup command" in TortoiseSVN
- Trying to use the cleanup command in Tortoise SVN I get an error about one of my folders not being a "working copy directory"
- Cleanup command in AnkhSVN does nothing.

I really can't do anything, what I would like to do is remove SVN support completely from my project and just start all over again, but I have no idea how to do this. This is all for my learning btw so it's not "mission critical". I have been doing manual backups and branching since my SVN failed to work a few months ago.

EDIT: Duplicate question, solved it using this answer

[How to get out of subversion source control in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824067/how-to-get-out-of-subversion-source-control-in-visual-studio)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get out of subversion source control in visual studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824067/how-to-get-out-of-subversion-source-control-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I use Agent SVN. I find it works well with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you use AnkhSVN inside VS, **forget about any and all external SVN-tools**
2. Start with new fresh project, read, understand and apply [AnkhSVN Get started](http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/com.collabnet.doc.anksvn_001/action/ankh_getting_started.html) doc

Comment: Thanks, I have done that and I'm going to start a new project and read through the documentation first. However I was able to remove the version control by deleting all the .svn hidden folders inside my project and removing the repository from the server